# Is it possible to use other Jupyter kernels in Spyder?

Tags: python, r, julia, jupyter, spyder

I know that the Spyder IDE can be used with iPython, the specific Python Jupyter kernel, but would be feasible (directly or with minor hacking) to use Spyder also with other Jupyter kernels, like the R or Julia ones ?

Comment: @vestland: The question you linked refers to connect Spyder to other running _iPython_ notebooks, while my question is to use other type of kernels. I received [an answer from Spyder developers](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7274#event-2997232683) that generalising Spyder to support multiple kind of kernels via plugins is in the roadmap for Spyder 5 (I'll have to wait although, as Spyder 4 has just been released)

Comment: I was wondering the same question about how to run Julia inside Spyder using it as a framework with tools for editing, debugging, documenting things using Jupyter Notebook.  A full IDE like Spyder has definite effciency advantages over Jupyter Notebooks or Jupyter Lab for large, multi-file projects.  What is the delivery timeframe for Spyder v5 ?